# Retrieving list of products from real time firebase android studio

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve all the products from the product structure in real time firebase. When I run the app crashes but when I comment "Product product = childSnapShot.getValue(Product.class);" it doesn't retrieve any data. Also when I try to retrieve from the Users structure it works.

Why does that happen?

```
public class User_products_list extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ListView listView;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    //Define Array list
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Define a ListView to display the data
    private ListView listViewdata;

    // Define an ArrayAdapter for the list
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_data);

       
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myRef = myRef.child("Products");

        
        listViewdata = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);

        // Set the ArrayAdapter to the ListView
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listViewdata.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    
                    Product product = childSnapShot.getValue(Product.class);
                    arrayList.add(product.getName());
                    arrayList.add(product.getDescription());
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: 1) "the app crashes" Please find the error message and stack trace in your logcat output, and include them both in your question. 2) We can't see your `Product` class. 3) Never leave `onCancelled` empty. At its minimum it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: Please provide the info Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.